# What kind of learning architecture can I use to solve a set of nonlinear thermodynamic equations?

Tags: neural-networks, math, architecture

I am in the business of solving equations based in thermodynamics. Technically speaking, I am trying to solve for the [binodals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binodal) for a ternary system. The binodal is a *curve* in a phase diagram.

Fundamentally, I am solving 3 nonlinear equations with 4 variables:

```
mu_a(pa_1, pb_1) = mu_a(pa_2, pb_2)
mu_b(pa_1, pb_1) = mu_b(pa_2, pb_2)
mu_c(pa_1, pb_1) = mu_c(pa_2, pb_2)
```

so there is one free variable which parameterizes the curve. Unfortunately, these curves cannot be solved analytically. They can only be solved for numerically.

Using python, I have written a program that painstakingly generates solution points `(pa_1, pb_1, pa_2, pb_2)`. This is an important development in solving for binodals, however, my program is memory-intensive and time-consuming.

My vision is that I can write a neural network to understand the solution of these equations and generate binodal curves, given certain inputs. I have a large number of binodals to train the neural network with, and given the right architecture, it should be possible for it to come up with the binodals given certain inputs. The input would be 6 inputs parameters that characterize the system, and the output would be a `1000x4` matrix (points on the binodal).

Would you have any suggestions for how to go about making a neural network/data-framework of this sort? I do not know much about neural networks apart from them being universal function approximators and robust regression devices. I would appreciate any advice you have for me!